# Pushing a sub-branch without rebasing

Tags: git, rebase

Say we have this topology:

```
X--X--X--             origin/master
    \     
     \     
      \--X--X--X--             b1 (private - not to be shared)
             \
              \
               \--X--X--X--    b2 (to be shared upstream)
```

We want to share only b2 but not b1, so we can do:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master b1 b2
git push origin b2
```

Is it possible to achieve the same goal without using rebase and changing local history? (pushing b2 sans b1 commits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Some `b1` commits are in `b2`'s history, so you'll have to rewrite history to get rid of those.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to think not of individual files, but of the commit objects as a whole. To get to b2, you need some of the commit objects from the second line.

```
A--B--C--                  master
    \
     \--D--E--F--          b1
            \
             \--G--H--I--  b2
```

In order to get the I commit, you need all the commit objects A, B, D, E, G, H, I.

So unless you rebase G from B you will not be able to exclude the D, E commits.